# import into two tables from one pydantic model

Tags: sqlalchemy, pydantic

I am using `Sqlalchemy` and `Pydantic`.

`Pydantic model`:

```
class ChildSubscribe(BaseModel):
    name: str
    child_name: str
    school: str
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

`Sqlalchemy model`:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20), unique=True)
    
    child_rel = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent_rel')
    
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20), ForeignKey(column='parents.name',
                                         ondelete='CASCADE',
                                         onupdate='CASCADE'))
    childName = Column(String(20))
    school = Column(String(20))
    
    parent_rel = relationship('Parent', back_populates='child_rel')
```

I know I can form a relationship like this:

```
parent = models.Parent(name=data.name)
child = models.Child(name=data.name, child_name=data.child_name, school=data.school)
child.parent_rel = parent
```

But I am wondering if there is a way to avoid duplication e.g., `name` in this case? Given the fact SQL models have a relationship, is it possible to populate both models with one Pydantic Model?

For an example something like this: (of course this gives error):

```
child = models.Child()
child.parent_rel = data.dict()
```

I am looking for a solution to somehow fill parameter space in SQL models from pydantic model with out defining name=pydantic.name etc etc.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want because there are inconsistencies in your example. Shouldn't the third field on `Child` be called `child_name` (the way you instantiate it)? Also do you _really_ have a foreign key relationship via the `name` field? Seems very strange, given that you have the `id` field on parent as the primary key.

Comment: Also, you know you can pass the parent object right away during initialization of the child, right?

Comment: The more I look at this, the stranger it becomes. Why are you both explicitly passing the foreign key value _and_ then also assigning the related object as well? You don't need to do _both_.